# How to find the running time of a specific procedure?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o, time-complexity, procedure

For each of the procedures below, let T (n) be the running time. Find the order of T (n)
(i.e., find f(n) such that T (n) ∈ (f(n)).

Procedure Fum(int n):

```
for i from 1 to n do    
 y ← 1/i
 x ← i
 while x > 0 do    
  x ← x − y 
 end while
end for
```

I know how to find run times of simple functions but since this is a nested loop where the inner loop depends on a variable from the outer loop, I'm having trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be **`1+4+9+...+n^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6`**, or simply **`O(n^3)`**, for this case.

For each step in the `for`-loop, it will run `i^2` times for the `while`. Given `x=i;y=1/i;`, it will take `i^2` (as `x=y*i^2`) times for `x` to reach `x<=0` by decrement step `x=x-y`.

For `i`, it will be `1,2,...,n`, summing them up, you will get `1+4+9+...n^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6`.

Comment: Thank you, can you tell me how you arrived at that answer?

Answer (score 0):

First, lets consider the runtime of the inner loop:
We want to figure out how many times the inner loop runs, in terms of i.
That is, we want to solve for f(i) in x-f(i)y = 0. If we sub in x = i, and y = 1/i, we get f(i) = i^2.

We know the outer loop will run exactly n times, so then, we get the total number of times the inner loop will be run:

= 1 + 4 + 9 + ... + n^2

This sum is equal to n(n+1)(2n+1)/6, which is **O(n^3)**

Comment: No, `1+4+9+... = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6`, not `n^2`.